# Why does CAST fail within CASE statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I am learning SQL from a website and working through exercises.

I am stuck in trying to understand why casting does not work in a CASE statement for one of the solutions I made below. What is the correct way to achieve this?

```
select
  patient_id,
  weight,
  height,
  case 
    when weight/power(((cast height as DECIMAL(4,2))/100.0),2) >= 30 then 1 else 0 end AS isObese
from
  patients
```

The only error I receive from the website is:

> near "height": syntax error

If I remove the cast and just run the below it works

```
select
  patient_id,
  weight,
  height,
  case 
    when weight/power((height/100.0),2) >= 30 then 1 else 0 end AS isObese
from
  patients
```

Comment: It's `cast()` not `cast`. You are missing brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing parhenteses?

try this

```
select
  patient_id,
  weight,
  height,
  case 
    when weight/power(((cast(height as DECIMAL(4,2)))/100.0),2) >= 30 then 1 else 0 end AS isObese
from
  patients
```

Comment: That's one of those "put your head in your hands" moments. Thank you for this, wish the error was more descriptive.